# jQuery Plugin: Get the "this" object inside other functions

Tags: jquery, plugins, this

I am trying to create a panorama slider as a jQuery plugin, and I have the following code:

```
 $.fn.panorama = function(settings) {

    var myPanorama = this;
    ..

    this.mousedown(function(e){

       //do stuff 
       $(this).css... //this all work
    }


    //Call mouseup on document in case user lets go of mouse outside draggable object
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $(myPanorama).easeDragging(); //works but probably not the way to do it
    this.easeDragging(); //ideal but refers to wrong object
 });

    }
```

My question is how do I refer to the `this` object inside the `$(document).mouseup` call?

Since it thinks `this` is the document itself and not the object attached to the plugin.

For now I am just making a variable and it works but there must be a better way!

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the way you achieved it *is* the simplest way to do it - storing a reference to *this*:

```
var myPanorama = this;

// ...

    myPanorama.easeDragging();
```

Alternatively, you can use [*jQuery.proxy()*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set the context of the function (thanks @Nick):

```
$(document).mouseup($.proxy(function(){
    this.easeDragging(); 
}, this));
```

The other way to do it is to use the ECMAScript 5th edition *.bind()* method, although you need to add this to the Function prototype for it to work in unsupported browsers:

```
// From Prototype.js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
      return fn.apply(object, 
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
    }; 
  };
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like so:

```
$(document).mouseup((function(){
    this.easeDragging(); 
}).bind(this));
```

Comment: You can also use `$.proxy()` here, e.g. `$.proxy(function(){ this.easeDragging(); }, this)` :)

Comment: @Nick: A very useful jQuery function that I didn't know about, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is just fine (and entirely correct).

One optimization tip though, there's no need to wrap it again since it's already a jQuery object, you can just do this:

```
myPanorama.easeDragging();
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you bind to the document in the first place (inside the plugin) and then work out if the event is useful to you (happening on your element, or a child of your element).

You should use a namespace if you are binding to the document eg.

```
$(document).bind('mouseup.panorama', function() {
    ...
}
```